# What would you put into the unit test of a repository class (data access layer)?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nhibernate, data-access-layer, iqueryable

I'd like to write a unit test for my data access layer to make sure that everything works allright in it.
The question is, what kind of things should I put into the tests?

The DAL is a static `Repository` class which hides the underlying layer (Fluent NHibernate) and exposes stuff to the public through an `IQueryable`.

I thought about

- CRUD (Create/Retrieve/Update/Delete) operations
- Transactions

Is there anything else about a DAL that is worth testing?
Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Repository implementation is tested with integration tests, not unit tests. Isolating repository implementation (mocking ORM) is almost impossible. Please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110981/the-repository-itself-is-not-usually-tested/7111748#7111748). Integration test uses a real ORM combined with real or fake (usually in-memory) database to do following:

- saving new object
- change -> persist -> restore sequence
- all 'Find' methods

Essentially you testing the correctness of:

- mappings (even if you use fluent)
- criteria
- hql or sql queries

Transactions are usually handled by an application layer, not repositories. You might be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322434/iqueryable-repositories-take-2/7323598#7323598) answer. Encapsulating IQueryable in the repository implementation will make testing a lot easier for you.

Comment: Why are you calling these "integration tests"?

Comment: Because unit implies *isolation*. When you see 'unit' read **'isolated unit'**. Isolating repository implementation from NHibernate is almost impossible. So you need integration test that verifies that **combination of the repository and real ORM** work together. Please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110981/the-repository-itself-is-not-usually-tested/7111748#7111748

Comment: Ah, yeah, you are correct. I've read that post, now I understand.

Comment: Indeed I want to test the *combination of the ORM and the repository*, and not the *repository alone*.

Comment: SQLite will not catch foreign key constraints, so there needs to be an integration test with the 'real' db too

Comment: You can easily stub or mock the repository, but this only makes sense to do in unit tests where the repository itself is not the SUT. Excellent answer Dimitry. Cheers

Comment: At the end I decided to use the test with a real DB, together with NHibernate's `hbm2ddl.auto`... it was effortless! Thanks @Dmitry and @Berryl

Answer (score 1):

1. Need to test proper Exception handling
2. Time Out Parameter of Database Connection
3. Time Out Parameter of Store Procedure invocation
4. Proper input parameters mapping . If store procedure expects to receive float but 
   receive int.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My DB doesn't have stored procedures. But your points are still valid!

Answer (score 1):

Usually in a DAL you don't have business logic, just plain db access code which is probably 1-5 lines long, so there is not to much to test ...

If you are sure you want to unit test it then i believe CRUD is fine. Mock out NHibernate, provide fake data and test against that fake data ;).

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Yeah, it's plain DB access, nothing fancy. Still, it would be good to have unit tests, because: 1. It's good to demonstrate that it works 2. Other members of the team can then look at it and see how to use the DAL.