# How to initialize an empty temp variable without having direct access to its type

Tags: c#, variables, reflection, initialization, repository-pattern

Suppose I have the following class and objects:

```
class Product
{ 
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public string ProductDesc { get; set; }
} 

string[] keywordArray = new string []{"A", "B", "C", "D"};    

var products = repository.GetAllProducts();
```

I use `var` because `GetallProducts()` returns a `IQueryable<Product>` but I cannot "see" the `Product` type since it is defined in my DAL.

Now I need a temp variable `tempResult` to store temporary results in a `foreach`. For example:

```
foreach(var keyword in keywordArray)
{
    tempResult = tempresult.Union(products.Where(p => p.ProductDesc.Contains(keyword)));
}
```

If I declare `var tempResult` inside the `foreach`, it is **overwritten** at each iteration (and it will give a **compile time error**, because it cannot be used before its initialization).

Therefore I need to inizialize it outside the foreach. If I use:

```
var tempResult = products;
```

Inside my `foreach` I just sum up to the whole set my desidered resultSet.

Therefore the only two possible solutions are:

1) Create a method in the Repository that returns an empty `IQueryable<Product>` (**factory pattern**)

2) Use **reflection** (if feasible, not sure yet)

I found both solutions a bit "dirty". Is there any other **approach/pattern** to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: add a using statement for your Product namespace (you're accessing its members, you're gonna need it afaik).

Comment: @alex You can get away without a `using` statement if you're just e.g. reading properties inside a lambda; you only need it if you need to reference the class somewhere by name e.g. a constructor, declaring a variable etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your code must be able to "see" the `Product` type since you're accessing `ProductDesc` and so on.

You just need to add a using statement for your DAL's namespace, or at worst set `tempResult` to `Enumerable.Empty<My.DAL.Namespace.Product>();`

Creating a whole method just to avoid referencing the namespace is unnecessary; using reflection is even worse.

On second thought, just call

```
var notTempResult = keywordArray.SelectMany(
    kw => products.Where(p => p.ProductDesc.Contains(kw)).Distinct();
```

to get your result without even having to reference the namespace.

Comment: Thanks but I am a bit confused. According to the Unit of Work from my Service layer I cannot use variables defined in my DAL right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. There's no code-based reason this shouldn't work.

Comment: No idea about your architecture. How do you propose to get anything out of your DAL if you can't use the classes defined in it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dynamic tempResult = null;

foreach(var keyword in keywordArray)
{

    if (tempResult == null) {
        tempResult = products.Where(p => p.ProductDesc.Contains(keyword));
    }
    else {

        tempResult = tempresult.Union(products.Where(p => p.ProductDesc.Contains(keyword)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to declare your tempResult as an IList and use a .ToList() on the union IEnumerable.

```
        string[] keywordArray = new string[] {"A", "B", "C", "D"};

        var products = repository.GetAllProducts();

        IList<Product> tempResult = new List<Product>();
        foreach (var keyword in keywordArray)
        {
            //declared because of access to modified closure issue.
            string keyword1 = keyword;
            tempResult = tempResult.Union(products.Where(p => 
               p.ProductDesc.Contains(keyword1))).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: If the questioner can't use `IQueryable<Product>` he won't be able to use `IList<Product>` or `List<Product>`.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I missed that part.  I thought it seemed too easy :P

Comment: Then I would try to redesign your repositories to not return IQueryable<>.  It is considered by many to be bad practice.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322434/iqueryable-repositories-take-2

Comment: well the problem is that I have a lot of data, and I need to use IQueryable in order not to take too much memory. I populate the collection once all the filtering is done. The only drawback is that I cannot use LINQtoObjects methods in IQueryable

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use linq expression and need not use any temporary variable.

```
 var result = products.Where(p => keywordArray.Contains(p.ProductDesc));
```